# Gradle build: Why doesn't 'exclude group' work with local projects

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

In my project I'm using a lib which uses an old version of the recyclerview.
But I want to use the newer version.

At first, i had the following problem:

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v7/recyclerview/BuildConfig.class
```

To solve this, I added the following to my gradle build (according to this [Issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=81804)), which works fine:

```
compile ('...'){
   exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'recyclerview-v7'
}
```

But when I create a local copy of the mentioned lib, I still get the ZipException.

```
compile (project(':...')){
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'recyclerview-v7'
}
```

I don't understand what might be the problem here. Can anyone give me a hint?
I also tried to rebuild everything, but it didn't help

Comment: I am facing the same issue, did you get a solution ?

Comment: @KrishnanVS Not really. I publish all my dependencies to an artifact server, like artifactory, which works nice.